# How can I run an ordered logistic regression without the function ignoring the weights?

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, non-linear-regression

Suppose I have this dataset:

```
require(rms)

newdata <- data.frame(eduattain = rep(c(1,2,3), times=2), dadedu=rep(c(1,2,3),each=2),
                      random=rnorm(6, mean(1000),sd=50))
```

I transform both the dependent and independent variables to factors

```
newdata$eduattain <- factor(newdata$eduattain, levels = 1:3, labels = c("L1","L2","L3"),
                            ordered = T)
newdata$dadedu <- factor(newdata$dadedu, levels = 1:3, labels = c("L1","L2","L3"))
```

and conduct a simple ordinal logistic regression with weights:

```
model1 <- lrm(eduattain ~ dadedu, data=newdata, weights = random, normwt = T)
```

Warning message:

```
In lrm(eduattain ~ dadedu, data = newdata, weights = random, normwt = T) :
  currently weights are ignored in model validation and bootstrapping lrm fits
```

I have reasons to believe that if the weights were being used the results would be quite different.

How can I fix it? Most questions that tackle this warning don't give proper answers to this specific warning.([here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/160638), [here](http://osdir.com/ml/lang.r.general/2004-12/msg00709.html), [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-July/108620.html))

Answer (score 0):

Someone would need to modify the code for `validate.lrm` and `predab.resample` in the `rms` package.  The code is on github at https://github.com/harrelfe/rms